# ArcGIS10 Highest point via polygon features

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, polygon, elevation, zonal-statistics

I am using **ArcGIS 10.0** with **3D Analyst**, **Spatial Analyst** and **Military Analyst**.

I feel like I am halfway to solving a problem but do not seem able to completely solve it.

- I have a polygon shapefile with about 100 polygons and each one has a unique ID.
- I want to overlay that on a raster and then for each polygon extract the highest value.
- I used the **Military Analyst>Highest Point** and also **Spatial Analyst>Zonal Statistics** and they both work.
- However, the main thing I need in the output is what polygon it is linked to.
- It seems like the zonal statistics work on zones but the id of the zone from the polygon is not transferred to the output.

So how can I get the max values back to the polygon shapefile to update a field?

Update: The solution I found was Zonal Statistics To Table in the Spatial Analyst Toolbox. I just selected ALL statistics.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like the asker was able to answer their own question, but did so through an edit to the question.

The solution was to use the Zonal Statistics as Table tool from the Zonal toolset of the Spatial Analyst toolbox.  A link to the ArcGIS Resource Center article is [here](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//009z000000w8000000.htm).  The option for ALL was chosen for the Statistics Type.

Comment: +1 Thank you for formally completing this thread with an answer.